# Howto access WMI in SQL CLR Projects

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, wmi, cpu

I have a project i've been working on that requires me to retrieve the CPU ID of the computer to create a software licence and check it against the current licens registered.

So, said and done i made 2 programs to make this happen. Then i need to implement this solution into my CLR project.

I notice that i can't add System.Management reference in an SQL Project.

So therefor i can't access the said controls to retrieve the CPU ID as i did in my other .NET programs.

Please ive been searching for a solution for this for a week now and any hints would really help. Ive seen people including the System.Management.dll at creation of the SQL Assembly but i really cant grasp how its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to create a web service that does the WMI stuff and returns the cpu id.

Alternatively if you want to go over to the dark side you could you could look at [xp_cmdshel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) and [OLE Automation Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189933.aspx) to access external resources.

Comment: Only problem with using a web service is you need to know its path.  My problem is FINDING that path, i.e. given a virtual path such as "/utilities", obtain its physical path.  Oops... you need WMI to do that or an endless chain of dependencies need added for System.Management.dll which ultimately can't be added to SQL Server.  So a hard-coded address to a web service would be out of the question, when the whole point of using WMI is to avoid using hard-coded paths to look up a virtual path.  This only applies to my particular problem, not the question this answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable the 'unsafe' option in your CLR project to be able to add a reference to System.Management.dll.  The System.Management.dll will then need adding to the datbase using `CREATE ASSEMBLY`.

Comment: System.Management.dll can't be added without dependencies. The very first error you'll get is: Assembly 'system.configuration.install' was not found in the SQL catalog." And when you try to add that, you'll get "Assembly 'system.runtime.serialization' was not found in the SQL catalog." and so on. All of these come with the warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'X' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working.